# Do we run out of questions?

Tags: discussion

If you take a look at our status in the [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators), all criteria seem to be satisfied (soon) but not the number of questions asked (which seems to be decreasing, actually). Do you think this is a problem for us? Is it something we should / can take care of?

Comment: It could be interesting to have data for other sites to compare, here is something for Academia SE which by intent and scope might be one of the most comparable sites to this one: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/283/keeping-track-of-our-stats

Comment: @quid Personally, I have many ideas and questions to contribute on this site in a wide range of subjects but unfortunately the behavior of some users seems inappropriate. Some of the like/close votes are not based on reasonable accurate justifications. Furthermore in some cases I received very explicit rude comments in my Main and Meta posts. This convinced me to stop my active participating here at least in a continuous way. I think the most important point is to show people that this is a *friendly* community not a place for some users to insult the others to prove themselves.

Comment: @SaintGeorg I am sorry that you are unhappy with the behavior of some users. I assume you know that you can bring behavior you consider as out of line to the moderators' attention via flags.

Comment: @quid I am not really interested in annoying my friends in community by flagging their posts. Furthermore many of the posts which I am talking about are not really offensive *by standards of flagging* but frankly they are really *unfriendly*. I think public implicit announcements like [Andrew's post](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/251/can-we-be-respectful) are better. However I think there are many really good and polite users in MESE particularly those who are from MO originally. I think this forum could be one of the bests if we are more careful about its culture.

Comment: @SaintGeorg I think this discussion leaves the intent of the current question a bit. If you would like to continue it, it could be better to start a new question. Just please note that the post you link to is very explicit regarding the fact that "not constructive" flags were raised. However, if you prefer not to flag but rather to discuss such things on meta this is also fine. Just let us not do so in comment thread of questions where it is not fully related to the question asked.

Comment: Just a comment on the q/d statistics: How do they calculate? At the moment, we have 270 questions and the site was created 23 days ago, but the statistics say 8.4??

Comment: @MarkusKlein The number on Area 51 is a median over the last two weeks. I'd also add that the targets on Area 51 are very rough values, I really would not worry about them too much. As long as there is a general upwards trend and no signficant problem with quality, there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 11):

This pattern is not unusual at all. Most sites go through a *honeymoon period* where users pile in from the excitement of a new launch with their questions at the ready. Then you experience a sharp drop in activity… followed by a pattern of slow, steady growth as you continue to compile content and the Google and network effects start to kick in.

This is all completely normal and expected.

Answer (score 6):

I think the fundamental piece is to accumulate **users** who ask high quality questions and/or provide high quality answers. The "we"/"us" you refer to is not static, of course, and the hope must be that the user-base on MESE continues to increase. How this accretion will manifest is still unclear (to me).

I don't think the concern you are putting forth is that there is a danger of running out of meaningful and tractable questions in *Mathematics Education* (i.e., as an area of study); but I remark, nevertheless, that such questions are certain not to run out in our lifetimes.